# Why does my SQL gave an error when i am using VARCHAR as primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE mactor(
pid VARCHAR(30) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (pid));
```

and this is the error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lname...' at line 2.

I am very confused and I don't want to use any other values as my primary key other than VARCHAR. please help!

Comment: What is an unsigned auto-incrementing *string*?

Comment: You probably don't want a VARCHAR as your PK since it would be very expensive to index, not to mention it can't be generated automatically by the DBMS.

Comment: Why do you want pid as `varchar` not as `int` or `long`? I would suggest to make it `int` or `long` . Make it PK and auto increment and if you want you can make `pid` as unique and add separate id column as PK

Comment: @viveknuna i am doing my class' assignment and it already given records to fill in into the database. thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the UNSIGNED; unsigned can only apply to numeric types, not character or binary types.  You will also need to get rid of AUTO_INCREMENT; you can't auto increment a character type.

Comment: was there something you hoped to accomplish by having it unsigned or auto_increment?

Comment: I am following my class' notes. all the primary key stated in my notes have unsigned and auto_increment on it. I guess I am not quite doing some reading for my class

Comment: @Chacha there’s no unsigned in sql server.